# Why is there no separate rep system in meta.movies?

Tags: support

Stack Overflow has its meta site meta.stackverflow, which supports separate reputation system in meta site. Why is this rep system separately for meta is not seen in meta.movies?

Is stack Exchange team changing their views on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is actually a rep counter in all meta sites (besides Meta.SO), but it is a hidden value.

Meta.SO has a separate reputation because it is also where one would go to report an issue with the site, post a feature-request, etc.

There have been SEVERAL talks about finally making Meta.SO just about SO and launching a Meta.SE for site issues, but the process has been a slow one and the devs have been working on a multitude of projects at once.

I will see if I can't dig up the Metas where they explain about the hidden Meta rep for each site.

---

[Kinda a reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78603/should-i-really-have-been-awarded-mortarboard-on-a-per-site-meta) I'm asking people who know more than me for advice like this.

Comment: This pretty much covers it. Meta is *about* the main site, so the abilities/reputation here should be based on your activity on the main site. The reasons to vote based on your knowledge/contribution become somewhat less clear in a meta discussion. We don't want people holding back on controversial, possibly-unpopular subjects just to protect their largely-meaningless "meta rep."